# Ghostscript - problem with character encoding

Tags: pdf, encoding, utf-8, ghostscript, postscript

I have a PDF/A document already OCRed by my scanner. The file is a little bit tilted, so I'm rotating it by 1 degree with ghostscript like this:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dSAFER \
   -dPDFSETTINGS="/screen" \
   -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true \
   -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -sOutputFile="out.pdf" \
   -c "<</BeginPage{1 rotate}>> setpagedevice" \
   -f in.pdf
```

(it's an adapted snippet from another SO thread)

It does it's job fine, however something with text encoding is not right - when I copy & paste the words with polish letters in it (ąśćęłńźż) from the original document, everything works fine, but when I copy & paste the same exact word from the PDF the command above produced, this polish letter's converted to '~' ("opłata" -> "op~ata", "wpłynęło" -> "wp~yn~~o"). How can I preserve the text? I really need it unchanged.

**EDIT:** Output of above command:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.25 (2018-09-13)
Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 3.
Page 1
Loading NimbusSans-Regular font from /usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.25/share/ghostscript/9.25/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Regular... 5076560 3564226 2614872 1261064 3 done.
Loading NimbusSans-Bold font from /usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.25/share/ghostscript/9.25/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold... 5142672 3737333 2635072 1280462 3 done.
Loading NimbusSans-Italic font from /usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.25/share/ghostscript/9.25/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Italic... 5310168 3943119 2816872 1460233 3 done.
Loading NimbusSans-BoldItalic font from /usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.25/share/ghostscript/9.25/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-BoldItalic... 5497480 4140597 3059272 1695969 3 done.
Page 2
Page 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the first thing to try is **not** to set SubsetFonts=true.

If your original PDF file doesn't have a ToUnicode CMap, then you r areliant on 'heuristics' (aka guesswork) to determine a Unicode point from a given character encoding.

If your original document works, then its likely that the character encoding matches ASCII or something similar. However, when you subset the fonts, the encoding gets altered. Essentially the first character encountered becomes encoding position 1, the second is 2, etc.

Naturally this causes problems when you try to cut and paste.

However, given that you are using characters outside the normal ASCII range, its unlikely that is the problem.

Its possible that you are using an old version of Ghostscript+pdfwrite (you don't actually say what version you are using, nor have you supplied the back channel output which would say) and its bug which has been fixed.

But frankly, without seeing the input PDF file, its pretty much impossible for anyone to figure out why the new PDF file is different, and therefore impossible to provide you with any useful advice other than guesswork.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention - I use Ghostscript 9.25. SubsetFonts=false did not help unfortunately and I cannot provide you with example pdf due to company privacy. I edited my original question with command output, maybe it can provide you any useful information.

Comment: No, not really, I can't see any obvious reasons, but then there's no real information to go on. You could try dropping EmbedAllFonts as well